# Dynamically add table rows to table or tbody element?

Tags: javascript, html

I've noticed that when I create a table with rows and stuff, chrome likes to automatically add a tbody element in between. Firefox also creates it but doesn't put the content inside it so it just kinda floats there.

Anyways, I'm dynamically adding rows to a table via js. Should I respect the browsers affinity for tbody and make the script add the children there instead of the table element?

Comment: *"so it just kinda floats there"* - Huh? What floats, the content or the tbody? Where does it float?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add table row in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Browsers automatically add `tbody` element to `table` if you didn't do it explicitly. A table may have single `thead`, single `tfoot`, and many `tbody` elements. Generally, a problem may occur when you use `table>tr` or (if you add several `tbody` tags explicitly) `table tr:nth-child()` selector.